# PHP in_array behaviour on non-associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I came across something which seems bizarre just now. Say you have the following array:

```
$arr = [0,1,2,3];
// Note the first element is 0
var_dump(in_array('random_string', $arr));
```

Outputs:

```
bool(true)
```

However

```
$arr = [3,1,2,3];
// Note the first element is NOT 0
var_dump(in_array('random_string', $arr))
```

Outputs:

```
bool(false)
```

Is there a logical explanation for this behavior?

Comment: `in_array` cast all array entries to the given needle. To get real valid checks use the 3 parameter and set it to `true`. But that is a bug what you are showing here, thing you should open an bugreport on php.net for this.

Comment: i get bool(true). if u search for 'random_string = 0' the second Array gives back false ofc. ( i understand that 1.2.3.4 is only a spacer)

Comment: What you mean saying `random_string`. It means string generates randomly?

Comment: @TaronSaribekyan Random string is just the string he's using in his example. It doesn't actually generate a random string...

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions It's actually the needle that gets type-juggled, not the haystack.  This is also not a bug because it's documented behaviour.  It is, however, a very horrible little gotcha that can catch even very experienced PHP coders out at times

Comment: @GordonM Yep, you are right. The string is cast to int and becomes 0. Mixed it a little up in my head. Not so unusual when working with php :-)

Comment: hhhmmm this is a horrible behaviour. Thanks for asking this question, now i'm aware of this...

Answer (score 2):

I'm betting your string is getting type-juggled to an int (and because the string has no sensible int representation the result is it casts to 0, which matches the first element)

Try adding a number to the start of the string you're using for your first example and you'll find that it will return true or false depending on whether the part of the string that's a number is in the array ("5 banana" will get type juggled to 5)

in_array has a third optional argument, a boolean that determines whether or not strict mode is used.  If not set or set to false then PHP will type-juggle the needle to match the type of the haystack and problems like this one will happen.  If you set it to true then no type-juggling occurs and strict comparison will be used instead.  This will stop the problem you're encountering, but at the cost that "2" will not longer match 2 and in_array will return false if you use "2" as the needle and [1, 2, 3] as the haystack.

```
$arr = [0,1,2,3];
var_dump(in_array('3 banana', $arr)); // true because "3 banana" == 3
var_dump(in_array('5 banana', $arr)); // false because "5 banana" == 5
var_dump(in_array('3 banana', $arr, true)); // false because "3 banana" !== 3
var_dump(in_array('random_string', $arr)); // true because "random_string" == 0
var_dump(in_array('random_string', $arr, true)); // false
var_dump(in_array('3', $arr, true)); // false because "2" !== 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening  because of non-strict comparsion. Your string casts into integer value "0", and this value we can see in first array.

[Example in PHP sanbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b6631dc5cee25c1185f05c796072d2de1640a25)

Answer (score -1):

Actually in_array return 0 and 1 value and as per your que its return 1 when u check

```
$arr = [0,1,2,3];
var_dump(in_array('random_string', $arr));
```

and `var_dump(in_array('random_string', $arr));` return datatype of 1 its boolean value(true) thats why its return bool(true) and other side when you check

```
$arr = [3,1,2,3];
var_dump(in_array('random_string', $arr))
```

`var_dump(in_array('random_string', $arr));` return datatype of 0 its boolean value(false) thats why its return bool(false)

Comment: next time edit your answer instead of writing a new one, now both will get removed